# RestSharp: Post Request returning "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: c#, restsharp

Using RestSharp to Method.Post Login Details to return a String. The API is returning "Method Not Allowed". In other parts of my application I have used RestSharp for different API's and they are working perfectly fine! So any suggestions on what I should try will be greatly appreciated!

This is the source code.

```
private async Task<bool> APIAuthenticate()
{
    string URL;
    RestClient client;
    RestRequest request;
   
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aiAuthToken))
    {
        Logging.Info("AskTheExpertFindCodes : Authenticating");

        string username = "UserNameExample";
        string password = "PasswordExample";

        URL = "https://APIExample/getToken";

        client = new RestClient(URL);
        request = new RestRequest("Gettoken", Method.Post);
        
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
       

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        
        request.AddJsonBody(new 
        { 
            username = $"{username}",
            password = $"{password}"
        });

        try
        {
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            var jsonResponse = response.Content.ToString();

            if (! jsonResponse.Contains("authtoken"))
            {
                aiAuthToken = "";
            } else
            {
                var oJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic(jsonResponse);

                oJSON = oJSON["return"];
                aiAuthToken = oJSON["authtoken"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { mFN.ShowError(this.Text, "AskTheExpert.Authenticate", ex.Message); }
}
```

This is the cURL command.

```
 curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://APIExample/getToken/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string"
}'
```

Comment: you have to post Gettoken too, pls

Comment: Thanks for putting the getToken in the CURL.

Comment: Seems that you're calling an HTTP Verb which doesn't exist on the server that you're trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a similar issue with Cognito API, which was picky about the `Accept` header value set by RestSharp. It is solved in the last RestSharp pre-release version.